# Can I mix type N mortar mix and type M mortar mix?

Tags: mortar

Can I mix type N mortar mix and type M mortar mix or does this have any adverse effects?

There is no specific purpose, I want to use up remainders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental difference is in the proportion of portland cement. Type M has a higher amount, and is therefore better suited for below-grade and high-strength applications. Type N is appropriate for lighter duty.

If you don't need to meet the requirements of foundation walls, for example, go ahead and mix it up.

[More information](https://www.archtoolbox.com/materials-systems/masonry/masonry-mortar-types.html)